# I want to make a telegram bot with php keyboards button not work properly

Tags: php, bots, webhooks, telegram

i want to make a telegram bot with php that ask some question one by one (keyboard buttons) and store details in object and finally answer something is exists or not!

i wrote this code

```
<?php
    require_once ("iphone_class.php");

    $message = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $result = json_decode($message, true);

    file_put_contents('test.txt', $result);

    $token = "255676049:AAEv9GbV95Xg2UmzZR4D-0kXbIj73NKnl4o";
    $base_url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/SendMessage?chat_id=";
    $chat_id = $result['message']['chat']['id'];
    $message_from_user = $result["message"]["text"];

    function AddtoKeyboard($names)
    {
        $ar = array(
            'keyboard' => array(),
        );
        foreach ($names as $name) {
            $ar2 = array($name);
            array_push($ar["keyboard"], $ar2);

        }
        return $ar;
    }

    function get_new_message(){
        $message = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $result = json_decode($message, true);
        $message_from_user = $result["message"]["text"];
        return $message_from_user;
    }

    if ($message_from_user == "موبایل") {

        $m = array("صفحه ی اصلی", "اندرویدی", "اپل");
        $keyb = json_encode(AddtoKeyboard($m));
        $rep = file_get_contents($base_url . $chat_id . "&text=" . urlencode("لطفا نوع موبایل مورد نظر را انتخاب کنید: ")
            . "&reply_markup=" . $keyb);

        $message_from_user = get_new_message();
        file_get_contents($base_url . $chat_id . "&text=" . urlencode($message_from_user));

        if ($message_from_user == "اپل") {

            $iphone = new Iphone();

            $m = array("صفحه ی اصلی", "5", "5c", "5s", "se", "6", "6 plus", "6s", "6s plus");
            $keyb = json_encode(AddtoKeyboard($m));
            $rep = file_get_contents($base_url . $chat_id . "&text=" . urlencode("لطفا مدل موبایل مورد نظر را انتخاب کنید: ")
                . "&reply_markup=" . $keyb);
            $message_from_user = get_new_message();
            $iphone->setModel($message_from_user);

            $m = array("صفحه ی اصلی", "16", "64", "128", "256");
            $keyb = json_encode(AddtoKeyboard($m));
            $rep = file_get_contents($base_url . $chat_id . "&text=" . urlencode("لطفا ظرفیت موبایل مورد نظر را انتخاب کنید: ")
                . "&reply_markup=" . $keyb);
            $message_from_user = get_new_message();
            $iphone->setCapacity($message_from_user);

            $m = array("صفحه ی اصلی", "silver", "gray", "gold", "roseGold");
            $keyb = json_encode(AddtoKeyboard($m));
            $rep = file_get_contents($base_url . $chat_id . "&text=" . urlencode("لطفا رنگ موبایل مورد نظر را انتخاب کنید: ")
                . "&reply_markup=" . $keyb);
            $message_from_user = get_new_message();
            $iphone->setColor($message_from_user);

            //TODO check ba database va message dadan quanity

        }else if ($message_from_user == "اندروید"){

        }


    } else if ($message_from_user == "لپ تاپ") {


    } else if ($message_from_user == "تبلت") {

        $text = "ipad";

    } else if ($message_from_user == "صفحه ی اصلی") {

        $m = array("موبایل", "تبلت", "لپ تاپ");
        $keyb = json_encode(AddtoKeyboard($m));
        $rep = file_get_contents($base_url . $chat_id . "&text=" . urlencode("صفحه ی اصلی") . "&reply_markup=" . $keyb);

    } else {

        $text = "hichkodoom";
        file_get_contents($base_url . $chat_id . "&text=" . urlencode($text));

    }

    ?>
```

but after

```
if ($message_from_user == "موبایل") {

        $m = array("صفحه ی اصلی", "اندرویدی", "اپل");
        $keyb = json_encode(AddtoKeyboard($m));
        $rep = file_get_contents($base_url . $chat_id . "&text=" . urlencode("لطفا نوع موبایل مورد نظر را انتخاب کنید: ")
            . "&reply_markup=" . $keyb);

        $message_from_user = get_new_message();
```

message wont update to last answer and my php file runs from begin and i lost my object iphone!

Comment: anything from error reporting? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php or are you busy watching that video from the answer below? *lol* which I might add, won't survive for very long.

Comment: i dont have any errors my problem is get_new_message method wont work properly or my solution to do this , is not correct

Comment: Please review the title of your question: 1) I have no idea how `keyboards button` or `keyboard buttons` relate to this post 2) a more conventional form might be `telegram bot does not work properly` - in question lists, the tags (including php in the first revision of this post) are shown prominently. (You (hopefully) did not lose you iPhone, you even get a new instance of `Iphone`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get new messages like this.

```
if ($message_from_user == "موبایل") {
        ...

        $message_from_user = get_new_message();
```

For every message, the php callback is called again (as you have also observed the behavior that your php code is running from the beginning for new messages). 
If you want to store messages from your users and interact with them, you should store the messages inside a database (or store inside the session), and then when you receive a message, check the chat id to see if you had any interaction with that user (for example any interaction in the past 10 minutes) or want to start over from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Use a switch case like this to distinguish between messages:

```
switch($message_from_user)
{
   case "موبایل":
   //do something
   break;
   case "اندروید":
   //do something
   break;
   case "اپل":
   //do something
   break;

}
```

Comment: Please format your post the next time. I did it for you this time.